# how to achieve the automaticaly number list function?

Tags: android-edittext

I want to achieve a easy funnction just similar to many editbox's function. as below:

1. one
2. two.
   This is so easy. The question is the cursor. When I tried to overwrite `onKeyListenner`, use `EditText.append()`. the number was correctly added. But the cursor will appear at next line. If I use `setSelection` to change the position. It would be turn to before the point.
   like this:
   1.fisrt line.
   2(cursor's place).
   Does anyone can help?

   ```
   if(event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN&&keycode==KeyCode_ENTER) {
     edittext.append("\n"+number+++".");
   }
   ```

It's show like this:

1. Fisrt
2. (cursor's position)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution:
Overwrite the onEditTextChangedListener
when event.getKeycode==Keyevent.enter
return true.
then it will be ok.